# How to use javascript to swap images with option change?

Tags: javascript

I need to make javascript code to swap images with option change. 
Here is the code:

```
<select name="Color:"onchange="document.getElementById('myimage').src = this.value;
">
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg">Black/White</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_by.jpg">Black/Yellow</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_byr.jpg">Black/Yelow/Red</option>

<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_by.jpg">Black/Yellow</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_nr.jpg">Navy/Red</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_nw.jpg">Red/Black/White</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_rb.jpg">Black/Red</option>
<option value="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_wrb.jpg">White/Red/Black</option>
</select>

<img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">
```

My problem is this: I need to have option values in plain text such as "Black/Yelow/Red" not a URL because this option value will show up in the check out page. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting up a mapping from your color options to the URLs might work, I think.

```
<script>
var colorUrlMap = {
    "Black/White" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg",
    //Add more here
    "White/Red/Black" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_wrb.jpg"
};
</script>
<select name="Color:"onchange="document.getElementById('myimage').src = colorUrlMap[this.value];">
<option value="Black/White">Black/White</option>
<!-- Add more here -->
<option value="White/Red/Black">White/Red/Black</option>
</select>


<img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use another attribute on the option:

```
<option value="Black/White" rel="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg">Black/White</option>
```

Then get that attribute with `getAttribute("rel")`

```
<select name="Color:" onchange="document.getElementById('myimage').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');">
```

Comment: Hi, Joel
I did this following your suggestion.

 <select name="Color:" onchange="document.getElementById    ('myimage').src = this.getAttribute('rel');"> 
<option value="Black/White" rel="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg">Black/White</option> 
<option value="Black/Yellow" rel="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_by.jpg">Black/Yellow</option> 
</select>
<img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">

But some reason it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It actually shouldn't be `this.getAttribute('rel')` but rather `this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel')`. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS and just change the class based upon the selection. Then all of your URL's are in a stylesheet.

CSS:

```
.red
{
background: url(red.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML/JS:

```
<select name="Color:" onchange="document.getElementById('myimageholder').setAttribute("class", "red");">
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
<HTML>
  <head>
    <TITLE>Image Select Test</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>

      function flip() {
          myimage.src = ColorSelect.children[ColorSelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute('url');
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      Select an image:<br/>
      <select id="ColorSelect" onchange="javascript:flip();">
        <option url="images/0.png"  value='Zero'>Zero</option>
        <option url="images/1.png"  value='One'>One</option>
        <option url="images/2.png"  value='Two'>Two</option>
        <option url="images/3.png"  value='Three'>Three</option>
        <option url="images/4.png"  value='Four'>Four</option>
      </select>

    </form>

    <img src="images/unknown.png" id="myimage"/>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
      // place this after <body> to run it after body has loaded.
      var myimage = document.getElementById('myimage');
      var ColorSelect= document.getElementById('ColorSelect');
  </script>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ColorSelect.children[ColorSelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute('url');` does not work.

It is rather `ColorSelect.options[ColorSelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute('url');`