# Change Image based on dropdown and image link

Tags: javascript, image

Expanding on the question here: [How to use javascript to swap images with option change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382461/how-to-use-javascript-to-swap-images-with-option-change/25290658#25290658)

In accordance with the method in that question of changing an image based on a select option, how would I also change the `<a></a>` link around the image to mirror the displayed image?

```
<script>
var colorUrlMap = {
  "Black/White" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg",
  //Add more here
  "White/Red/Black" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_wrb.jpg"
};
</script>
<select name="Color:"onchange="document.getElementById('myimage').src = colorUrlMap[this.value];">
  <option value="Black/White">Black/White</option>
  <!-- Add more here -->
  <option value="White/Red/Black">White/Red/Black</option>
</select>

<img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">
```

example:

```
<a href="WHATEVER IS CHOOSEN BASED ON THE urlMAP"><img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing multiple things now, it would be better to break that change code into its own function. But basically you need to access the `href` attribute of the `a` tag the same way you are accessing the `src` on the `img` tag.

```
<script>
    var colorUrlMap = {
        "Black/White" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg",
        //Add more here
        "White/Red/Black" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_wrb.jpg"
    };

    function changeSelect(el) {
        document.getElementById('myimage').src = colorUrlMap[el.value];
        document.getElementById('link_id').href = colorUrlMap[el.value];
    }
</script>
<select name="Color:" onchange="changeSelect(this)">
    <option value="Black/White">Black/White</option>
    <!-- Add more here -->
    <option value="White/Red/Black">White/Red/Black</option>
</select>

<img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage"> 

example:

<a id="link_id" href="WHATEVER IS CHOOSEN BASED ON THE urlMAP"><img src="images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg" id="myimage">
</a>
```

You may notice that I also gave the `a` an `id` value.

**update**

If you need to get that link from somewhere else, here is a possible alternative way to write your script. I added another level of properties to each color item: a `src` and `href` to match the attribute names you are updating on the `a` and `img` tags.

```
<script>
    var colorUrlMap = {
        "Black/White" : {
            "src" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_bk.jpg",
            "href" : "your link here"
        },
        //Add more here
        "White/Red/Black" : {
            "src" : "images/taylormade_purelite_standbag_wrb.jpg",
            "href" : "your other link here"
        }
    };

    function changeSelect(el) {
        document.getElementById('myimage').src = colorUrlMap[el.value].src;
        document.getElementById('link_id').href = colorUrlMap[el.value].href;
    }
</script>
```

**update 2**

To address the question in the comments about radio buttons, yes. From your code example, currently you have a form submission on the `onclick` event of the radio. You would need to change that. The trick with `radio` buttons however, is that you only want to use the value of the selected radio. If you use the `onchange` event on the radio, it will fire both when it is selected and deselected.

So if you want to use the same function for both radios and selects, you can wrap the setter lines in an if statement:

```
function changeColor(el) {
    if (el.nodeName != "INPUT" || el.checked) {
        document.getElementById('myimage').src = colorUrlMap[el.value].src;
        document.getElementById('link_id').href = colorUrlMap[el.value].href;
    }
}
```

This should work on `select`, `input[type=radio]`, and `input[type=checkbox]`. You can put it in a `onclick`, `onchange`, or `onkeyup` handler. (`onkeyup` is good when the keyboard is used to change the values.)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, THIS WORKS PERFECTLY! Out of curiosity is it possible to do this same thing but using an <input type="radio"> like the example below?

Comment: <div style='width: 65px; height:100px; padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px; float: left;'>
  <label for='". $row['uniqueID'] ."' style='cursor:pointer;'>
  <img class='inputbox' src='". $row['color_img'] ."' alt='". $row['color_name'] ."' width='60' height='auto'>
  <p class='colorpallet'>". $row['color_name'] ."</p>
  </label>";
<input class="inputbox" id="'. $row['uniqueID'] .'" type="radio" name="finish" onmouseenter="document.getElementById('. $basehood .').src = colorUrlMap[this.value];" value="'. $row['color_value'] .'" onClick="this.form.submit()" style="display:none; cursor:pointer">

Comment: Please update your question with the new example (so we get proper formatting.. code doesn't work well in comments). Also, don't forget to mark the answer if it was what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was reading you should wrap the radio in a div and listen for the div mouseover event, (Which is what I need). I think the bigger problem is that my radio's are hidden and called with a label onclick. Do you have a suggestions for getting this to change with a hidden radio on mouseover (when them mouse hovers over the lable). Thanks

Comment: @ChrisKsag: I understand. That would qualify as a different question as it is beyond the scope of your question above. If my solution solved the above question, please mark it as the answer. In either case, please post a new question with the new criteria. Thanks!